# Рантайм typeid(*ptr)

Tags: c++, указатели, rtti

Мне надо проверить, является ли `T* ptr` типом `Base` (rtti включён).

Конструкция

```cpp
dynamic_cast<const Base*>(ptr) != nullptr;
```

работает корректно, однако происходит лишнее бессмысленное преобразование

Поэтому я попытался использовать

```cpp
typeid(Base) == typeid(*ptr);
```

Однако он просто отказывается работать. Смею предположить что `typeid(*ptr)` рассчитывается в компилтайме, так как `*ptr` имеет тип `T` (`template<typename Base, typename T>`)

При этом сравнение проверяет конкретный тип, когда `dynamic_cast` - возможность преобразования дочернего типа к родительскому

Подскажите, можно ли как то решить данную проблему?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` проверяет что `*ptr` это наследник `Base` **или** самого этого класса. `typeid` проверят фактический тип. Это разные сравнения. см : [C++ dynamic_cast vs typeid for class comparison duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704893/c-dynamic-cast-vs-typeid-for-class-comparison)

Comment: @AlexGlebe, ох, тупанул, спасибо большое

Comment: @AlexGlebe А есть ли другой подобный метод, или это надо вручную реализовывать?

Comment: метод чего? Я помню в базовом классе сделал переменную `int tip;` из `enum{..типы..}` и быстро всё сам проверял. Если вам это надо..

Comment: чтобы как-то ответить, вам надо показать минимальную конфигурацию классов с примером.

Comment: @AlexGlebe зачем? Я полностью описал задачу - проверить, наследуется ли тип A от типа B в рантайм

Comment: Из ваших объяснений не понятно почему вам нужна рантайм проверка. У вас есть разименование указателя? Если это так то либо ручной труд либо dynamic_cast. Если разименований нет то вполне сгодиться старый добрый компиледтайм is_base_of

Comment: @Nikolay У меня нет информации о типе в компилтайме, и её никак нельзя получить. А dynamic_cast по сути создаёт лишнее преобразование, разве нет?

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей в преобразовании нет ничего страшного. Тут только проблема в скорости работы, т.к. нужно заглянуть в vtable в рантайме на каждый вызов dynamic_cast, ну и соответственно для этого должен быть хотябы один виртуальный метод чтобы этот vtable у класса появился.

Comment: @Nikolay 1) При включенном rtti vtable и так создаётся 2) Это зависит от компилятора, и в стандарте нет чётких указаний о том, как хранится информация о типе. Я и хочу убедиться в том, что dynamic_cast не сжирает лишние ресурсы на преобразование одного типа в другой (по идее не должен)